# How to get GMT from the below javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

How to get GMT from the below javascript code?

```
var output=new Date("05/23/2104 10:15PM");
```

I want the result as : 05/23/2104 22:15

Comment: You date is not parsed like this.  You need a space: `output=new Date("05/23/2104 10:15 PM");`

Answer (score 0):

You're input string should be different:

```
var output=new Date("05/23/2104 10:15 PM"); // Note the space between `15` and `PM`
```

Then you just concatenate the different parts:

```
output.getDate() + "/" + 
(output.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + 
output.getFullYear() + " " + 
output.getHours() + ":" + 
output.getMinutes()
```